# JSON Objectmapper issue

Tags: java, jackson

Getting both java obejct as will jsonproperty is getting generated whilc I convert java object to JSON.

Can you please confirm where I have made mistake.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25893985/362792

Comment: @Hitobat The problem is I need the xApiheader and xApiheaderCc. As if you see I have changed the name to x-apiheader-cc and x-apiheader in sample JSON. But I am getting all xApiheader and xApiheaderCc(which should be as  x-apiheader-cc and x-apiheader)

Comment: You can use @JsonIgnore for the fields which you don't want to serialize.

Comment: Try removing your getter, or move JsonProperty annotation to getter method.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)` to your class:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) 
public class FalconidePersonalizationVO {
```

By default Jackson follow java bean convention to output json properties. As result, it founds your `getX` method and output `xapiheader` property.

But you also annotate your field with `@JsonProperty` so another property named `x-apiheader` is also ouputed.

Disable `getterX` detection method will prevent jackson output getter fields.

Answer (score 0):

**************** **Solution 1** ****************

Annotate getter / setter with @JsonProperty as well (now annotating field is not mandatory)

```
public class FalconidePersonalizationVO {

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader-cc")
    private String xApiheaderCc;

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader")
    private String xApiheader;

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader-cc")
    public String getXApiheaderCc() {
        return xApiheaderCc;
    }

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader-cc")
    public void setXApiheaderCc(String xApiheaderCc) {
        this.xApiheaderCc = xApiheaderCc;
    }

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader")
    public String getXApiheader() {
        return xApiheader;
    }

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader")
    public void setXApiheader(String xApiheader) {
        this.xApiheader = xApiheader;
    }
}
```

**************** **Solution 2** ****************

Follow setter / getter naming convention. In normal naming convention first letter of field name is capitalized prepending it with set / get. But in this case since second char is capital so, first char is not capitalized. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146215/3295987

```
public class FalconidePersonalizationVO {

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader-cc")
    private String xApiheaderCc;

    @JsonProperty("x-apiheader")
    private String xApiheader;

    /*
     * Setter / getter auto generated in eclipse
     */
    // getXApiheaderCc -> getxApiheaderCc
    public String getxApiheaderCc() {
        return xApiheaderCc;
    }

    public void setxApiheaderCc(String xApiheaderCc) {
        this.xApiheaderCc = xApiheaderCc;
    }

    public String getxApiheader() {
        return xApiheader;
    }

    public void setxApiheader(String xApiheader) {
        this.xApiheader = xApiheader;
    }
}
```